# Zend DB union count

Tags: php, zend-db

I have 2 selects, which are unioned, something like this:

```
$select->from ( array (
                'A' => 'tableA' 
        ), array (
                'field1',
                .....
        ) );
$select2->from ( array (
                'B' => 'tableB' 
        ), array (
                'field1',
                .....
        ) );
$select3 = $this->getAdapter()->select ()
            ->union(array($select1, $select2));
```

And now, based on the union, I want to do this:

```
$select3->reset ( 'columns' )->columns ( new Zend_Db_Expr ( 'COUNT(DISTINCT(field1))' ))
```

But I'm getting this error:

> No table has been specified for the FROM clause

Which is technically correct, but I do not want the count from a table, I want the count from the result in my union. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working it around like this:

```
$select3->reset ( 'columns' );//->columns ( new Zend_Db_Expr ( 'COUNT(DISTINCT(field1))' ))
$sql = $select->__toString();
        $countQuery = <<<EOD
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(res.field1)) as total_rows FROM ($sql) as res
EOD;


        $countResult = $this->getAdapter ()->query($countQuery)->fetchAll();

        $count = 0;

        if (! empty ( $countResult )) {
            $count = $countResult [0] ['total_rows'];
        }
```